# Why does this one single accesskey not work on Firefox?

Tags: forms, firefox, access-keys

I'm using Firefox on MacOS and a *specific* access key isn't working:

```html
<label id="name_label" for="name" accesskey="n">Name</label>
<input id="name" name="name" value="" tabindex="1" type="text" />
```

This works on Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox. When I use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, the focus is not set on the "name" field. There are 2 other fields in the form, and their access keys work as expected. There are no conflicts on the page for the access key (i.e. `accesskey="n"` is only defined once). There are no conflicts on the page for the target element name (i.e. `id="name"` is only defined once).

I can use the developer tools to change the accesskey on that label to something else (e.g. `w`) and it works, so the link between the `<label>` and the `<input>` is correct. There is something about the `n` specifically.

I haven't been able to find any information online about any "access keys that don't work (for some reason)" but I'm starting to wonder if the `n` access key conflicts with something in Firefox.

Installed plug-ins are [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#ublock-origin), [Firefox Devtools ADB Extension](https://github.com/mozilla/devtools-adb-extension), and [Power Close](https://github.com/mos3abof/firefox-power-close).

Comment: I am having _exactly_ this problem, with the same key, the N key, in a Thunderbird add-on that I maintain. Thunderbird uses a lot of the same codebase as Firefox so I'm pretty it's the same issue. I wish I could figure it out, it's preventing disabled users who need the access key for one of my add-on's buttons from being able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly figured out what is causing this and came up with a workaround that's good enough for my purposes though I don't know if it will be useful for yours.

On macOS, when you type Option-N you're telling the OS that you want to put a tilde accent over the next character you type. This makes the Option-N key sequence a "dead key", which means that it doesn't generate any actual characters until another key is pressed.

Now, when you type **Ctrl**-Option-N, that shouldn't be treated as a dead key, right? But either the macOS keyboard input layer or Firefox (and Thunderbird, which uses the Firefox code base), I'm not sure which, is still treating it as one. I confirmed this by intercepting the key event in JavaScript and examining the event structure; the `key` field of the structure is set to `Dead`. I imagine this will happen not just with the N key but with any key that is used on macOS for generating accented characters.

As a workaround in my Thunderbird add-on I added a keydown handler which check is Ctrl and Alt (a.k.a. Option) are true on the key event, *and* the `key` field is set to `Dead`, *and* the `Code` field is set to `KeyN`, and if so, then I invoke the function that should have been invoked automatically by the access key. Here's a code snippet suitable for a keydown event handler:

```
if (event.key == "Dead" && event.ctrlKey && event.altKey &&
    event.code == "KeyN") {
  event.preventDefault();
  theNAccessKeyThing();
}
```

You can see the whole thing [here](https://github.com/Extended-Thunder/send-later/commit/80de9504619652db6c435b067efcb0b970a60fac) if you're curious, but the code above is enough to get you started.

This only works if the user hasn't remapped the "N" key on their keyboard, because we're using the pre-mapping key code instead of the mapped key sequence, but it'll work fine for the vast majority of people.

I've reported this to Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1850454

I've also added telemetry to my add-on to find out how many people are running into this, because I figure if a lot of people are running into it that'll help me convince someone at Mozilla to spend some time trying to figure it out.

Comment: That's amazing detective work, and it does "make sense" to someone (me) who hasn't thought about it very much. I haven't tried it at all, but other keys like this would be Option-E (accent), Option-U (umlaut), Option- Option-` (accent), and [some others](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/enter-characters-with-accent-marks-on-mac-mh27474/mac). Not being able to use E, U, I, and N is quite limiting.